# Passing struct* and loading the struct in other function

Tags: c, pointers, structure

It doesn't compile, I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong. When I try to do:

```
(ultimo->siguiente)=nnodo;
```

the compiler doesn't let me. Neither does work:

```
scanf("%d", &(nnodo->dni));
```

PD: baja and modif functions are still not done but they shouldn't make any conflicts with the main program.

---

Compiler Output(Visual Studio 2010):

Error   2   error C2037: left of 'siguiente' specifies undefined struct/union 'stru'    c:\documents and settings\emiliano\desktop\asdc.c   52  1   abm

Error   3   error C2037: left of 'dni' specifies undefined struct/union 'stru'  c:\documents and settings\emiliano\desktop\asdc.c   55  1   abm

4   IntelliSense: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed   c:\documents and settings\emiliano\desktop\asdc.c   52  3   abm

5   IntelliSense: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed   c:\documents and settings\emiliano\desktop\asdc.c   55  15  abm

---

I think I did the typedefs correctly, but I really do not know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stru* pstru;

typedef struct{
    int dni;
    pstru siguiente;
}stru;



pstru alta(pstru ultimo);
pstru baja(pstru ultimo);
pstru modif(pstru ultimo);
int menu(pstru ultimo);

int main(){
    pstru ultimo;
    ultimo=(pstru)malloc(sizeof(stru));

    menu(ultimo);
    return 0;
}

int menu(pstru ultimo){

    int opc;
    printf("Para alta (1), para baja (2), para modif (3), para salir (4)\n");
    scanf("%d", &opc);

    switch(opc){
        case 1:
            ultimo=alta(ultimo);
            break;
        case 2:
            ultimo=baja(ultimo);
            break;
        case 3:
            ultimo=modif(ultimo);
            break;
        case 4:
            return 0;
    }
    menu(ultimo);
    return 0;
}

pstru alta(pstru* ultimo){
    pstru nnodo;
    nnodo=(pstru)malloc(sizeof(stru));
    (ultimo->siguiente)=&nnodo;

    printf("Ingrese DNI\n");
    scanf("%d", &(nnodo->dni));

    ultimo=nnodo;

    return ultimo;
}

pstru baja(pstru ultimo){
    return ultimo;
}

pstru modif(pstru ultimo){
    return ultimo;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, you can't do:

```
typedef struct stru* pstru;

typedef struct
{
    int dni;
    pstru siguiente;
} stru;
```

You've defined an untagged structure type and called it `stru`, but the `typedef struct stru *pstru;` refers to a different tagged structure type, `struct stru`, which is incomplete.

You probably need:

```
typedef struct stru *pstru;

typedef struct stru
{
    int dni;
    pstru siguiente;
} stru;
```

This should compile without problem.

---

In C++, you would not need the second `typedef`; you could simply write:

```
typedef struct stru *pstru;

struct stru
{
    int dni;
    pstru siguiente;
};
```

and the type `stru` would be defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jonathan. You were right, now it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something that leads to undefined behaviour in your `alta` function.

First of all you try to assign a `stru **` to a `stru *`. This the compiler won't allow as the types are different.

The part that will lead to undefined behaviour is that you are using `&nnodo`, that is taking the address of a *local variable* and try to store it. This will not work as local variables are on the stack, and when a function returns it's stack is reclaimed by the compiler to be used by other variables and functions.

Comment: OK, I fixed the scanf part.

Now, having pstru alta(pstru ultimo) as the function definition and declaration should work right?

Because I tried it and I still get the same compiler output.

Comment: Thanks, Joachim I can't upvote your answer due to newbie reputation but your help was really appreciated.